# Step-by-step replace like in Vim

Tags: emacs

Vim allows to do step-by-step replace with the syntax `s/<regexp>/<substitute>/gc`.

How can I such a thing with Emacs?

Comment: Run [VILE](http://invisible-island.net/vile/)... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the [Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/index.html) (inside Emacs: `C-h i` then `m emacs RET`), 
go to the section [“Replace”](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Replace.html#Replace) (`m replace RET`), and there see [Query Replace](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Query-Replace.html#Query-Replace). “Query replace” the Emacs name for what Vim calls a substitution with confirmation.

The command `query-replace-regexp` is bound to `C-M-%`. (On a text terminal, you may be unable to type this keychord; you can use `M-x query-replace-regexp` instead.) To replace a plain string (i.e. without wildcarsd), there's also `query-replace`, bound to `M-%`.